# Carry last Factor observation forward and backward in group of rows in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have dataset which looks like

```
ID Name 
1  JAY
1  
1  JAY
2  LAY
2  LAY
2  
3  NA
3  KAY
3
```

I want to fill the rows with missing values(empty or with NA) based on the observation already available in the group. So the resultant data frame will look like

```
ID Name 
1  JAY
1  JAY
1  JAY
2  LAY
2  LAY
2  LAY
3  KAY
3  KAY
3  KAY
```

I tried using `na.locf` but it didnt work for non numeric value.

```
DF1 = setDT(DF)[,  N := na.locf(na.locf(Name(NA_real_^!Name),na.rm=FALSE), fromLast=TRUE, na.rm=FALSE), ID][is.na(N), N := 0]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is after grouping by 'ID', subset the 'Name' that are not `NA` and not a blank (`nzchar(Name)`), get the last observation (`tail(...)`) and assign (`:=`) it to 'Name'.

```
setDT(DF)[, Name := tail(Name[!is.na(Name) & nzchar(Name)], 1), by = ID]
DF
#   ID Name
#1:  1  JAY
#2:  1  JAY
#3:  1  JAY
#4:  2  LAY
#5:  2  LAY
#6:  2  LAY
#7:  3  KAY
#8:  3  KAY
#9:  3  KAY
```

If the 'Name' column is `factor` change the `nzchar(Name)` to `nzchar(as.character(Name))`

---

Or specify the logical vector in the 'i'  and assign (`:=`) the last observation (`Name[.N]`) to 'Name' after grouping by 'ID'

```
setDT(DF)[!is.na(Name) & nzchar(Name), Name := Name[.N], ID]
```

Note: For the second solution to work, the 'Name' should be `character` class.

Answer (score 3):

Solution in base R (using `split` and `do.call(bind, ...`). Assume `d` contains your `dataframe`:

```
tmp <- lapply(split(d, d$ID), function(x) { 
    # Explanation:
    # decreasing = TRUE so that empty strings are at the end
    # na.last = NA so that NA's are omitted
    x$Name <- sort(x$Name, decreasing = TRUE, na.last = NA)[1];
    return(x);
})

d.new <- do.call(rbind, tmp);

print(d.new);
ID Name
1.1  1  JAY
1.2  1  JAY
1.3  1  JAY
2.4  2  LAY
2.5  2  LAY
2.6  2  LAY
3.7  3  KAY
3.8  3  KAY
3.9  3  KAY
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an another solution for the dplyr enthusiasts, use `fill()` from the `tidyr`package. Specify the direction in which you want to fill the missing names `c("down", "up", "downup", "updown")`.

```
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% fill(Name, .direction = "updown")
```

Answer (score 0):

`na.locf` works on text vectors, I think your data.table syntax might be messing with it. I haven't used that package much so can't say how.

This works fine:

```
df <- data.frame('ID' = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
                 'Name' = c('JAY', '', 'JAY', 'LAY', 'LAY', '', NA, 'KAY', ''),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df$Name <- na.locf(df$Name, fromLast = TRUE) # takes care of 'KAY'    

df[df==''] <- NA

df$Name <- na.locf(df$Name) # takes care of the rest
```

The base R solution already posted is also very good, splitting by ID gives you more control over how replacements happen. I've done something similar with by() before.