# Forward and backward fill data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame in with data as follows

```
Col1    Col2 
20      NA    
25      NA     
15      NA
NA      10
NA      15
```

and so on... I am looking to reshape it as follows

```
Col1     Col2
20        10
25        10
15        10
15        10
15        15
```

Basically to forward or backward fill NA values with the first occurring non NA value. I tried a variation of [Carry last Factor observation forward and backward in group of rows in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40479001/carry-last-factor-observation-forward-and-backward-in-group-of-rows-in-r), but was unable to get it to work...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `tidyr::fill` works, e.g. `df %>% fill(everything()) %>% fill(everything(), .direction = 'up')`

Comment: @alistaire: Thanks! I believe when you mention everything() its ncol(df) to account for doing this action over all columns in the DF?

Comment: `everything()` is a helper function from dplyr that just tells the function to act on all the columns. Specify the columns any way you could in `dplyr::select`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We can do this with `na.locf` from `zoo`

```
library(zoo)
na.locf(na.locf(df1), fromLast = TRUE)
#  Col1 Col2
#1   20   10
#2   25   10
#3   15   10
#4   15   10
#5   15   15
```